# Prepositions over and on

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In my English book, there are 2 pictures:

1- The man is on/over the floor.
(Description: The man is touching his feet on the floor and lingering there)

2- The man is over/on an armchair.
(Description: He is sitting on an armchair, like someone usually do)

Which one is the right preposition for each case?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're trying to describe. Is the man hovering above the floor? Is the man sitting on the back of the armchair?

Comment: The man is just standing up on/over the floor. And yes, he is sitting on the back of the armchair.

Comment: Are his feet *touching* the floor, are are they touching something else and it's just his head or the rest of his body that is now on top of the floor? (You should put all of this explicit description into the question itself.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will put this description right now.